# Make a jQuery Mobile listview Sortable by Drag & Drop in Phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

There are a few questions on this site and others similar to this, but none work for my implementation on Phonegap 2.9, jQuery 2.0.3, and jQM 1.3.2.

The general consensus is that you need to incorporate jQuery UI and a small library called jQuery UI Touch Punch to 'fool' jQuery UI's mouse events for touch events.  You can see that approach on this blog: http://forresst.github.io/2012/06/22/Make-a-list-jQuery-Mobile-sortable-by-drag-and-drop/.  Basically, you just include the jQuery UI and Touch Punch libraries and use this syntax:

```
<script>
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
<!-- Refresh list to the end of sort to have a correct display -->
$( "#sortable" ).bind( "sortstop", function(event, ui) {
  $('#sortable').listview('refresh');
});
});
</script>
```

But, alas, this doesn't work when I use it within my Phonegap Build app.  I can clearly drag and drop a listview `<li>`, but the listview never refreshes to actually finish off the drop.  The maddening part is that there's a demo at http://forresst.github.io/demos/sortable/en/index.html that works perfectly fine on my test mobile browsers.  All of them, but it just doesn't work when embedded into Phonegap.

I have found through trial and error, that if the page has a RESET button on it, when I press the RESET button the listview item snaps into place.  So, logically I tried to simulate this with `.click();` calls, but those haven't worked.  I've searched the interwebs and tried my best to follow the stacktrace within the phonegap app, but I haven't found a solution.  Also, I'd love to not have to incorporate jQuery UI into my jQuery Mobile app.

Has anyone found a working solution for the current versions of Phonegap and jQuery Mobile for a user to drag and drop a sortable list?

Comment: I have the same issue.  The demo sites mentioned in other posts work but not when deployed to phonegap.  I'm trying to create a list of images that represent a story and the  have the end user move them to create a story order of their choosing.  Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that, in general, reducing the dependency on jquery's sortable functionality while constructing a Cordova/Phonegap environment is time well spent.  Sorting html table elements in a mobile app work great with [https://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable](https://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/)/

Comment: obviously, someone here is very proud of jquery, downgrading an answer that suggests an alternative library